# Can we use corePHP code in wordpress?

Tags: php

I am a newbie to WordPress, and after exploring WP I come to know that it is purely developed in OOPS PHP.

So my question is can I develop wordpress website using normal php (corePHP) for simplicity, As i don't know OOPS.

Short answers in YES/NO will also be appreciated because i don't want you to write whole lengthy explanations.
THANKING YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use 'normal PHP'. It is not necessary to use object-oriented PHP. Also, WordPress is not all OOP, a lot of it is just functions and functional based programming.

Comment: Hello @Milan sir, THANKS for your reply. I understood it clearly.